# Short story about military airships and a dragon corps

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, dragons, steampunk

I'm looking for a short story that appeared in an anthology of either fantasy or science fiction stories.

- I believe the story is called "The Day is Saved"
- Personal Honor was an important aspect of the story
- There was a rivalry between the dragon riders and the army (navy?)
- The army/navy was equipped with cannon-firing airships
- I believe the dragons were more of a royal-guard/jedi type then a standing military unit
- I recall some monarch-type elements that kept the dragons in play even over the airships 'superior military advantage'
- The battle was fought more than once (perhaps more than twice) with the military losing the first time
- They were besieging some sort of castle-like fortified structure
- I believe they were fighting in the mountains
- The airships were a relatively new invention in the story
- I think the airships were held aloft by magic
- The castle was also held together by magic, it was being actively 'repaired' by wizards renewing the magic
- Magic is spelled unusually with both a C and a K (magicks) in this story.
- Crafters are used to create and reverse-engineer magic
- Airships are lost if they travel to far down to the "Bottom" (capitalization from the story)
- The initial battle, led by the military, was lost due to an ambush
- Only the attacking faction (which had the dragons) had airships, the other side did not.

Handful of Character Names:
Jeantrou, Hastind, General Dennis

Unfortunately I read the story in a used book store, so the book is also likely to be on the older side.

Comment: @Raj I cannot conclusively say that the story I read was NOT part of a larger series.  I vaguely remember looking up the author at the time and not finding anything else (and being disappointed enough to remember this), but I may have made any number of mistakes that mean this could be part of a series. I am not 100% on the title either.

Comment: @user14111 I read it about two years ago, but it was in a book in a used book store, and I have no idea what the history of the book is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks like it may be [*Privateer*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2391277) by Margaret Weis and Robert Krammes.  A Google book search shows a "General Dennis," a "Captain Jeantrou" and a "Lord Captain William Hastind."

The cover shows dragons and a flying sailing ship with cannon.

[image: Cover of Privateer]

The Google books description mentions a "dangerous mission to the dark world of the Bottom Dwellers."

Comment: I am not sure if this is the STORY that I read, but this looks like what I am looking for. Let me do some digging!

Comment: If you look at the "Short Fiction" section of [Margaret Weis' ISFDb page](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?671) you'll see a number of titles marked "(excerpt)."  One of those might be an excerpt of this novel; without tracking them all down it's hard to tell.  But they will each list where they were published, and you might recognize a cover.

Comment: I'm accepting this as the answer. This book actually contains what I believe is a synopsis of the actual story (You can read it here: https://bit.ly/2KXJrUK). I had no idea there were more books written in the same world! Super excited now, excellent find.

Comment: Here's the actual book, found in her short stories collection as you suggested @DavidW http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?274024